# Is there a way to convert a Vim regex literal to different magic modes?

Tags: regular-expression

If I have a magic Vim regex in a string literal, is there a way to convert the whole regex into an alternative representation that uses a different magic mode, so I could paste that equivalent regex into source code?

For instance, if I want to convert this magic-mode pattern:

```
'\m-\=\<\d\+L\=\>\|0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]\+\>'
```

to very-magic-mode to make it more readable, something like:

```
'\v-=<\d+L=>|0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+>'
```

I often make mistakes trying to convert them by hand.

Comment: I'm not aware of one. Do you plan to always have them in single quoted strings?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/Iup5uXBiFGg/RfuCpTFrT-sJ) could be a starting point. I have however it only barely tested.

Comment: concerning the question title, it is hard, think about converting a very magic regex `[0-9]+` into  a no magic one... ;-)

Comment: So I've been trying to make [a plugin](https://github.com/statox/VimRegexConverter) for that, it kind of work but it is far from being perfect. Also for the reference there is a plugin which converts ruby/perl regex to Vim regex, the code is... huge: [eregex](https://github.com/othree/eregex.vim)

Comment: I'm getting that overall there's no simple/complete solution but there are some patterns that can help for some cases. I wonder if vim's code could be modified into a tool to check patterns for equality based on some internal representation after parsing it or something.

Comment: @statox Nice. https://github.com/tpope/vim-scriptease would be a good home for a utility like that.

Comment: @MuMind: I'm not a regex theory expert but I think that testing patterns equality is a really hard task and more importantly it is not really the role of a text editor, maybe it would be better to have an external tool to do that? Also my little plugin is still really buggy I don't think it would really have the same quality as the tools developed by a vimguru like Tim Pope :)

Comment: @statox I just mean symbol-for-symbol equality if it's handy inside the vim internal representations, and yeah I meant an external tool.

Comment: @statox A good implementation in scriptease would still be nice, and yours is a start that could be improved in code review. All software is buggy when it's first written.

Comment: @MuMind I think I don't understand which type of comparison you're looking for :-) And about the improvement of the plugin, don't hesitate to test it an use github to signal a bug or even suggest a pull request, I'll gladly look a it!

Comment: @statox I just meant that `\v(a|b)` and `\m\(a\|b\)` are trivially the same, there's a 1-to-1 translation between those forms, and there may be an easy way to equality check those if there's not a good way to convert between them automatically. It's a tangent, though, I pbb shouldn't have brought it up.

Answer (score 4):

The command

```
:s\v\\(\W)/\1/
```

should suffice to transform most any pattern into `\v` mode. It won't swap out the lil' `\m` marker though - and to my knowledge that's impossible in a single replacement. It's short enough to type manually though, and then you can just do `:s/\\m/\\v` for the mode marker.

`\W` is shorthand for `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]` which is the (negated) set of characters that very magic mode operates on. This just deletes any backslashes immediately preceding one of those characters.
**Known issue:** This will replace `\\` inside strings to `\`. You could replace `\W` with `\c[^a-z0-9\_]` to mitigate this, but it'll still mess up your regex literal if you run it multiple times and also fail on longer escape strings (containing `\\\\` for example)

**Update:** The original question makes it unclear if you need to transform `\v` back to `\m`, but the command there is:

```
:s/\v(\\)@<!(\c[^a-z0-9\-\\\[\]\'_])/\\\2/
```

Answer (score 0):

based on @Wolfie's answer:

`:subs #\v\\(\W)#\1#gc`

to use `#` instead of `/` (I hate `/` and `\` together):
`:subs ^\/^#^gc`

May need some manual check